# Collide function only taking x and x+width?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I think I have an issue will my collisions, normally if you collide with a platform I have it so it acts as quicksand. However if the platform is too small it does not hit the x or x + width and same for y so the player falls down fast. How can I solve this?

http://www.taffatech.com/Platformer.html

This is my collision code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Platforms.length; i++) {

    if (Player.x > Platforms[i].x 
        && Player.x < (Platforms[i].x + Platforms[i].width)) {

        if (Player.y + (Player.height) > Platforms[i].y 
            && Player.y < Platforms[i].y + Platforms[i].height) {

            Player.jumping = false;
            Player.playerColour = "orange";
            Player.velY = 0;
            Player.velX = 0;
        }
    } else {
        gravity = 0.3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
playerWidth = width of the square the player moves; //assign your value here
for (var i = 0; i < Platforms.length; i++) {

if (!(Player.x < (Platform[i].x-playerWidth) || (Player.x > (Platform[i].x+Platform[i].width)))) {

    if (!(Player.y < (Platform[i].x-playerHeight)) || Player.y > (Platform[i].y+Platform[i].height))) {

        Player.jumping = false;
        Player.playerColour = "orange";
        Player.velY = 0;
        Player.velX = 0;
    }
    } 
else {
    gravity = 0.3;
}
}
```

Let me know if this works otherwise we have to try something else if we missed out some case. And yeah by the way congrats, you are building on a very good concept keep going.